# Can my approach for this 'verification by Induction' be simplified?

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, induction, alternative-proof

### Sorry:

I don't know math scripting, so arguments maybe clumsy, sorry.

### Problem (let's take sub-question (c) for simplicity)

[image: problem pic]

So, the problem is:
**Given:** a<sub>1</sub> = 1 and a<sub>n+1</sub> = ((2n + 1)/(n+1)).a<sub>n</sub> for all n >= 1
**To find (and verify its truth by Induction):** a<sub>n</sub>

### My approach:

**Let P<sub>n</sub>:**
(definition for a<sub>n</sub> I'm assuming to be true)
a<sub>n</sub> = 1, if n = 1
OR
a<sub>n</sub> = ((2n-1)/n).a<sub>n-1</sub>, if n > 1

> Note: The style **given: a<sub>m</sub>** and **a<sub>n</sub>: a<sub>m</sub>** means value of a<sub>m</sub> obtained by **given** definition (a<sub>1</sub> = 1 or formula for a<sub>n+1</sub>) and  a<sub>n</sub> definition (the one I **assumed** to be true).

**P<sub>1</sub>:**
given: a<sub>1</sub> = 1
a<sub>n</sub>: a<sub>1</sub> = 1
given: a<sub>1</sub> = a<sub>n</sub>: a<sub>1</sub> => **P<sub>1</sub> is true**

**Now assume P<sub>n</sub> is true**:
Case 1: **n = 1**
a<sub>n</sub>: a<sub>1</sub> = 1
a<sub>n</sub>: a<sub>2</sub> = ((2(2)-1)/2).a<sub>2-1</sub> = 3/2
given: a<sub>2</sub> = ((2(1)+1)/(1+1)).a<sub>1</sub> = (3/2).a<sub>1</sub>
substituting a<sub>n</sub>: a<sub>1</sub> here,
given: a<sub>2</sub> = (3/2)
here a<sub>n</sub>: a<sub>2</sub> ==  given: a<sub>2</sub>
=> **P<sub>1</sub> implies P<sub>2</sub>**    --- (1)

case 2: **n > 1**
a<sub>n</sub>: a<sub>n</sub> = ((2n-1)/n).a<sub>n-1</sub>
a<sub>n</sub>: a<sub>n+1</sub> = ((2(n+1)-1)/(n+1)).a<sub>(n+1)-1</sub> = ((2n+1)/(n+1)).a<sub>n</sub>
given: a<sub>n+1</sub> = ((2n+1)/(n+1)).a<sub>n</sub>
here a<sub>n</sub>: a<sub>n+1</sub> = given: a<sub>n+1</sub>
=> **P<sub>n</sub> implies P<sub>n+1</sub>**    --- (2)

(1) and (2) => P<sub>n</sub> => P<sub>n+1</sub> for all n >= 1,therefore, **P<sub>n</sub> is true for all n >= 1**

So, the definition of a<sub>n</sub> is
**a<sub>n</sub> = 1, if n = 1

OR

a<sub>n</sub> = ((2n-1)/n).a<sub>n-1</sub>, if n > 1**

### question:

1. Is my approach correct?
2. Is there any simpler approach?

### EDIT 1: Clarification

my question's solution is **No, my approach is wrong, I need to find an explicit formula for a<sub>n</sub>**.

This may be the context you need to understand my question clearly :
My assumed formula for a<sub>n</sub> was not an "Explicit" formula; I didn't know what it means. I transformed the given formula by replacing n with n-1 to get a formula for a_n (of the form a<sub>n</sub> = f(a<sub>n-1</sub>)) and thought I need to prove this **transformed definition** is true using induction principle, and that's what I did here. Thanks to @coffeemath for explaining what "Explicit formula" means.

Comment: An explicit formula for $a_n$ cannot refer to the value(s) of $a_k$ for some $k<n.$ Instead it must be an algebraic expression in the variable $n.$ You have not given one, and I suggest you calculate many actual values to find a pattern.

Comment: Cinv--- you DID refer to $a_{n-1}.$ Explicit = formula in $n$ *only*, not referring to any previous values of $a_n.$

Comment: @coffeemath yeah, I agree, sorry, I misunderstood your comment. I deleted that comment. thanks. I didn't know meaning of "explicit formula", so I ignored it

Comment: @coffeemath if we ignore that the formula for a_n has to be "explicit", have I proved my recursive definition for x_n correctly? If yes, is their any simpler method (in proof by induction method) to prove this recursive definition?

Comment: I am confused by what you mean by proving the recursive formula, since that is already given in the statement of the problem.

Comment: @coffeemath I thought the transformation of the definition from a_n+1 = f(n) to a_n = f(n-1) form really needed a proof. Here, I just replaced n+1 in the original formula with n to get assumed definition for a_n, and I thought this new definition really needed a proof for its correctness because I thought that in general, this kind of simple replacement of n+1 with n may yield a transformed definition that is not true everytime.

Comment: @coffeemath in explicit formula, can I define special value for a_1 (like a_n = 1 if n == 1) and then define general formula in terms of n for a_n where n > 1?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150772/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-cinverse).

Comment: It does not make sense, you can't prove a definition.

Answer (score 1):

I note you are asking only about problem 9 part (c) in which $$a_1=1,\ \ a_{n+1}=\frac{2n+1}{n+1}a_n.\tag{1}$$
I found that an explicit formula is given by
$$a_n = \frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{2^n}.$$
Here the numerator is the central binomial coefficient, and the formula may be established by induction using the factorial version of the binomial coefficient, i.e. $(2n)!/(n!)^2.$ The algebra for the induction step is left for you; it is fairly straightforward using some simple properties of factorials.

**added:**
This same recurrence and formula is associated with the Taylor series of $1/\sqrt{1-2x}$ centered at $0$ whose general term is $a_nx^{n-1}, n \ge 1.$

Comment: another (simpler) explicit formula: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64965063#64965063

Comment: Your formula is really not "explicit" in the sense that as n ingreases, the number of terms also increases. Compare the two formulas for the sum of first n integers: A) 1+2+...+n and B) n(n+1)/2. In formula A we must add n terms to get the result, which of course may be as large as  one wishes for large enough n. In formula B we can for any n get the answer by one multiplication and one division by 2, so 2 calculations.

Comment: but even your formula involves factorial, which also involves terms that increase as n increases, right? If you call factorial as an operator therefore it is a single term, even I can define an operator, say B, such that B(n) = (2n-1)...7x5x3x1, so then my formula is x_n = B(n)/n!, which then I can call it as an Explicit formula, right?

Comment: Yes you are correct. So in that sense I would guess there is not a formula involving finite calculation. When I put this into Wolfram Alpha, it gave an answer in terms of the Gamma function. I don't know whether that function is considered a closed form or not. I guess only the author of the text can say what is meant by "explicit formula" for this problem.